# Javascript: What is definition of the "control"?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, **what is the definition of "control"?** Is it the same thing as the browser's javascript interpreter?

Here are two places I've been reading it:

> "When **control** comes across such a statement, it immediately jumps out
>   of the current function and gives the returned value to the code that
>   called the function." [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html)
>
> "Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after
>   throw won't be executed), and **control** will be passed to the first
>   catch block in the call stack. If no catch block exists among caller
>   functions, the program will terminate." [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Comment: It's probably just a way of referring to what is essentially the instruction pointer, but I could be wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow

Comment: @PaoloMoretti was one sec faster than me. This isn't JS-specific, it's a general CS concept.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an imperative programming language. As such, it works by executing statements in some order, one after another. Thus at any given moment there is a point in the program that is "currently executing".

This current point of execution is variously referred to as "program counter" (PC), "instruction pointer" (IP), or simply "control".